# How to configure custom host in Restify in Cloud9IDE?

Tags: node.js, cloud9-ide, restify

I am not able to give custom host address as process.env.IP to restify server. It is required since Cloud9 IDE works on process.env.IP & process.env.PORT

```
var restify = require('restify');

var server = restify.createServer({
  certificate: ...,
  key: ...,
  name: 'MyApp',
});

server.listen(8080); //process.env.PORT will go here instead of 8080
```

Answer (score 0):

Cloud9 will also accept 0.0.0.0 as the IP and 8080 as the port.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it is accepting 0.0.0.0 as IP and 8080 as PORT. I was wondering if there is any way of passing custom IP in express similar like replace server.listen(8080) with server.listen(8080,'0.0.0.0')